# Sony Camera Remote API actTakePicture error 40400 (shooting fail) with RX0

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I am able to connect to RX0 using `sony_camera_api` and call some methods like `setShootMode` or `getFocusMode`. However, whenever I call `actTakePicture` to take pictures, I will always get error 40400.

There are very rare times when I call `actTakePicture`, I can hear the RX0 performing auto-focus. However, the camera will never proceed to perform any image capturing.

The very same code can work with Sony A6500.

Any possible reason for shooting failure? Thanks in advance.

I was trying out Python script from arcoslab/ros_sony_cam. Error was returned after self.cam.actTakePicture()

```
        self.cam.setShootMode(param=['still'])

        # set timestamp for picture
        now = time.time()
        self.hdpic_tstamp = Time(now)

        # get status snapshot of cam
        event = self.cam.getEvent(param=[False])

        if "error" in event:
            self.polled_image_resp = self.polled_image_error(str(event['error']))
            return

        # check if is available to take pic
        if event['result'][1]['cameraStatus'] != 'IDLE':
            rospy.loginfo("Camera is busy")
            self.polled_image_resp = self.polled_image_error("Camera is busy")
            return

        # take pic
        self.hdpic_resp = self.cam.actTakePicture()
        if 'error' in self.hdpic_resp:
            rospy.logerr(self.hdpic_resp['error'])
            self.polled_image_resp = self.polled_image_error(str(self.hdpic_resp['error']))
            return
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code in your question. Did you already research what the error code `40400` means?

Comment: I've seen that on the a7iii too. You need to set selftimer to at least 2sec.

Comment: I've noticed that error too, actHalfPressShutter before actTakePicture seems to work reliably.

Comment: jeah but you have to wait until Focus Status goes to focues else you can't take a Picture even after actHalfPressShutter (For Focus Status Always call getevent for changes)